# Python Tkinter: Parsing dropdown menu value into a function as a variable?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, tkinter, pytorch

I am trying to create a Tkinter dropdown menu to add into the main GUI. The purpose of the menu is to give the user several options to choose the image segmentation neural network (currently there are only two options).

I am having trouble getting the value of the dropdown menu and parsing it through the function as a parameter (variable, not a string).

I have tried creating a `staticmethod` within the GUI window class to search for the value of the dropdown menu and parse the value through the image segmentation function when the segment button in the GUI is pressed. The segmentation function takes two parameters, `net` and `path`, where it is neural network and image file pathway respectively.

I am not too sure how to change the individual parameters of a variable so I just changed the whole variable depending on the value of the dropdown menu. The only thing being changed is the `net` parameter of the segment function bind to the Tkinter button.

The code:

```
@staticmethod
    def find_option():
        if menu1.get() == "fcn":
            App.btn2 = Button(App.btn_frame, text="Segment", width = 10, height = 1, cursor = "hand2", command=lambda: App.segment(net=App.fcn, path=App.path))
        else:
            App.btn2 = btn2 = Button(App.btn_frame, text="Segment", width = 10, height = 1, cursor = "hand2", command=lambda: App.segment(net=App.dlab, path=App.path))
```

The dropdown menu code:

```
fcn = models.segmentation.fcn_resnet101(pretrained=True).eval()
dlab = models.segmentation.deeplabv3_resnet101(pretrained=1).eval()
options = ["fcn", "dlab"]

variable = StringVar(btn_frame)
        variable.set(options[0]) # default value

        menu1 = OptionMenu(btn_frame, variable, *options)
        menu1.pack(side=LEFT)
```

`btn_frame` is the frame within the main window containing the buttons.

`App` is the main GUI class. `menu1` needed to be referenced as `App.menu1` but it would, for some reason, cause several errors (other class variables would become `undefined` and it would say `App object has no attribute menu`). I also tried referencing `menu1` as `App().menu1` but would initiate a new window each time I pressed the segment button, also it never actually showed the segmented image.

Comment: You should use `variable.get()` instead of `menu1.get()` as `OptionMenu` does not have `get()`.

Comment: @acw1668 Thanks for your comment. So if I'm understanding you correctly, if I change the `find_option` function to `variable.get()` it still gets the value of the dropdown menu? I'll go try it now. edit: hey, I got a `undefined` error for `variable` and when adding `App.variable`, I got `App object has no attribute variable`.

Comment: If the code is part of a class, then better changing `variable` to `self.variable`.  Is `App` the name of the class or instance of the class?

Comment: App is the name of the class but is a subclass of `Tk()`. I think adding `self` will solve the problem. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Then you can't use `App.btn2`, should be `self.btn2`, except it is a class variable.

Comment: Yeh, you're right I had to change all the buttons and frames to `self`. edit: Oh and one more thing, I am getting a `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable` with the segment button, `command=lambda: self.segment(net=self.find_option(), path=self.path))`. I changed the `find_options` function to take `self` as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I think you want something like this. It's hard to know when I can't see the entire code, but could it be that you are forgetting ot pass `self` ot the `find_option` method?

```
# This is the option menu part
self.options = ["fcn", "dlab"]
self.variable = tk.StringVar(btn_frame)
self.variable.set(options[0]) # default value
self.menu1 = tk.OptionMenu(
    btn_frame, self.variable, *self.options)

self.menu1.pack(side=LEFT)

# And then later you have this method (remember to pass self to find_option)
def find_option(self):
    if self.variable.get() == "fcn":
        # your code
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, does using `variable.trace` change the parameter value within the function bind to a button? It is desired the value from the dropdown menu change the value of the parameter and not actually run the segment function directly when the menu value to changed. Thanks again.

Comment: I misunderstood. @acw1668 is right. Change it to `value = variable.get()` :-)

Comment: Thank you! However, I am getting two different errors with the `find_options` function. I got a `variable undefined` when calling `variable.get()` directly and `App object has no attribute variable` when calling `App.variable.get()`. This also happens when I change the staticmethod into a classmethod.